# DropDownListFor wrong value selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dropdownlistfor

in MVC 3 i have a EF code first class like this:

```
 public class Client
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(4)]
    [Display(Name="labClientID", ResourceType=typeof(Resources.Translations.Client))]
    public string ClientID { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="labName", ResourceType=typeof(Resources.Translations.Client))]
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Client is used eg in following Person class:

```
  public class Person
{

    [Key]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ForeignKey")]
    [MaxLength(4)]

    public string ClientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Clients have IDs like 01,02,03 etc

In an edit view I have the following razor statement for the edit person view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientID , new SelectList(ViewBag.Clients, "ClientID", "Name"))
```

The ViewBag.Clients is build up before with:

```
ViewBag.Clients = (from x in Context.Client select new {x.ClientID, x.Name});
```

Now comes the strange part: Indepented which value I choose for the ClientID in the person class, the DropDownList always displays the second entry from the client table when I open the edit view that contains the DropDownListFor statement.

I debugged the clients viewbag and it contains the correct values, also I used a editorfor instead of an DropDownListFor and the clientid in the person entity has the correct value.

Have you an idea where the problem is?